# Eliminar todos los archivos en una carpeta de mi servidor FTP con asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para eliminar todos los archivos que hay en una carpeta de mi servidor FTP pero no he tenido éxito
Este es el código que uso para listar mis archivos:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string url;
        url = "ftp://server/";
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        List<string> directories = new List<string>();

        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            directories.Add(line);
            line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();
}
```

He probado con el siguiente código dentro del WHILE pero me marca un error

```
FtpWebRequest reques = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + directories);
        reques.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
        reques.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        FtpWebResponse respons = (FtpWebResponse)reques.GetResponse();
        string status = respons.StatusDescription;
        respons.Close();
```

Si alguien tiene una manera de como hacerlo estaría muy agradecido, buen día!!!

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error? ¿Tienes los permisos para eliminar dichos archivos?

Comment: En qué difiere esta pregunta de [tu pregunta de unas horas antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/597614/21)

Comment: @fredyfx si tengo todos los permisos, el error ''El URI solicitado no es válido para este comando FTP', esto pasa por que al momento de listar los archivos, los enumera desde el cero 0 y  elimina todos los archivos excepto el del valor 0

Comment: @jachguate en que ya cuento con ambos métodos (listar y eliminar) pero no encuentro la manera de unificarlos

Comment: Ninguna de las dos preguntas menciona esa dificultad. En mi opinión debiera ser una sola pregunta, que explique lo que has intentado, que tienes esos métodos y las dificultades que estás encontrando. No veo razón para tener dos preguntas en este caso, pues el problema parece ser uno solo.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea extraño pero,
He encontrado una solución, la cual fue agregar un Foreach después de crear la lista para poder eliminar archivos de uno en uno, así:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string url;
        url = "ftp://server/";
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        List<string> directories = new List<string>();

        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            directories.Add(line);
            line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }
        foreach (string file in directories)
        {
            ///ELIMINAR ARCHIVOS
            FtpWebRequest reques = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + file);
            reques.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
            reques.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            FtpWebResponse respons = (FtpWebResponse)reques.GetResponse();
            string status = respons.StatusDescription;
            respons.Close();
        }

        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Espero que esta solución le funcione a alguien en un futuro